# Magento 2 - Reverting cancel orders programmatically

Tags: magento2, sales-order, cancel-orders

For some reason order canceled in bulk through my customly added `order cancel` mass action. Now I need to uncancel all orders.

- Change status from cancel to the status that was previously set on order
- Change state of order that was previously set
- Subtract all quantities of products which are used in the order that are just reverted by cancelling.
- Remove order history comments

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a helper in any of your module

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php
```

And use following code:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Indexer\Stock\Processor as StockProcessor;
class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockManagementInterface
     */
    protected $stockManagement;
    /**
     * @var StockProcessor
     */
    protected $stockIndexerProcessor;

    public function __construct(
        Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockManagementInterface $stockManagement,
        StockProcessor $stockIndexerProcessor
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function uncancleorder($order, $comment = "")
    {
        if(!($order)){
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Invalid Order'));
        }

        if ($order->isCanceled()) {
            $state = Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
            $productStockQty = [];
            foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                $productStockQty[$item->getProductId()] = $item->getQtyCanceled();
                foreach ($item->getChildrenItems() as $child) {
                    $productStockQty[$child->getProductId()] = $item->getQtyCanceled();
                    $child->setQtyCanceled(0);
                    $child->setTaxCanceled(0);
                    $child->setDiscountTaxCompensationCanceled(0);
                }
                $item->setQtyCanceled(0);
                $item->setTaxCanceled(0);
                $item->setDiscountTaxCompensationCanceled(0);
            }

            $order->setSubtotalCanceled(0);
            $order->setBaseSubtotalCanceled(0);
            $order->setTaxCanceled(0);
            $order->setBaseTaxCanceled(0);
            $order->setShippingCanceled(0);
            $order->setBaseShippingCanceled(0);
            $order->setDiscountCanceled(0);
            $order->setBaseDiscountCanceled(0);
            $order->setTotalCanceled(0);
            $order->setBaseTotalCanceled(0);
            $order->setState($state)
                ->setStatus($order->getConfig()->getStateDefaultStatus($state));
            if (!empty($comment)) {
                $order->addStatusHistoryComment($comment, false);
            }

            /* Reverting inventory */
            $itemsForReindex = $this->stockManagement->registerProductsSale(
                $productStockQty,
                $order->getStore()->getWebsiteId()
            );
            $productIds = [];
            foreach ($itemsForReindex as $item) {
                $item->save();
                $productIds[] = $item->getProductId();
            }
            if (!empty($productIds)) {
                $this->stockIndexerProcessor->reindexList($productIds);
            }
            $order->setInventoryProcessed(true);

            $order->save();

        } else {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('We cannot un-cancel this order.'));
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Note: Edit this helper according to your requirements.**

Now call `uncancel` method anywhere, just pass order object and comment(if required)

Reference module: https://github.com/Genmato/M2_UnCancelOrder

Comment: Useful and detailed answer.

Comment: How to support MSI in Magento 2.3?

Comment: It misses coupon/store credit/promotions handling.

Comment: Worked well for me. Thanks broski

Comment: Order is reverting back to processing state but the salable quantity is not getting effected. Any one faced this kind of issue in magento 2.4.4

Comment: @RajeshSelvam, Please check if you have enabled this configuration "Set Items' Status to be In Stock When Order is Cancelled" and try again, if this works or not, please let me know.

Comment: I think this answer is incomplete, as this doesnt undo the insert in the inventory_reservation table

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer doesn't consider MSI. in order to avoid generation a salable qty issue. You could also add this code,

`

public function fixReservationForUncancel(String $incrementId, String $sku, int $qty){

```
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager */
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    /** @var Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection */
    $resourceConnection = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::class);

    $connection = $resourceConnection->getConnection();
    $tableName = $resourceConnection->getTableName('inventory_reservation');

    $insertQuerry= [
        'stock_id' => 1,//Check your stock id in the same reservation table
        'sku' => $sku,
        'quantity' => $qty*-1,
        'metadata' => '{"event_type":"order_uncancel","object_type":"order","object_id":"","object_increment_id":"'. $incrementId .'"}'
    ];
    
    $qry= $connection->insert($tableName, $insertQuerry);

}
```

`